# Showing Error Message

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, html

When I run this program and enter Dan Dan inside of it, it works.  Now when I enter http://sftpgamblerlotteryclub/www it doesn't work.  I would like for it to catch the sftp, /, www and return back to the form and inform the user " this is not a username, please resubmit".  Thanks you.

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = "";
$name = $email = $subject = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
           $nameErr = "Name is required";
        } else {
         $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-']*$/",$name)) {
        $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
            }
        }
}

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft FrontPage 5.0">
<meta name="ProgId" content="FrontPage.Editor.Document">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Contact Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
Name:
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr; ?> </span>
    <br><br>
<input name="submit_btn" type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="Send Mail">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
echo $name;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test_input function is striping out the / so that is removed before you do your preg_match. As such you will never catch the /.

If I understand your question you want to make sure the user name is not in a list of prohibited names. For that I would create an array of prohibited names and then do a stripos on the json_encoded output of the array within a if condition. This makes it easy to expand the list of prohibited names.

This is based on your code snip-it.

```
$array = ["sftp", "http", "www"];
if (stripos(json_encode($array),$name) !== false) {
  $nameErr = "This is not a valid user name"
}
```